# Bean Scopes Managment in JSF + Spring

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jsf-2

I am building a application using JSF2.0 + Spring 3.0 .My beans are managed by Spring in this application.
In this application I have a form which have 3 SelectOneMenuItems(JSF)

1. When user select 1st dropdown box value it then it will populate 2nd dropdown box(As i have placed logic in EventChangeListener)
2. And when user select value from 2nd drop down it will populate 3rd drop down according to the selection of 2nd drop down

Now When I submit the form, it will submit fine but it doesn't not remove the values from the box.
I tried **request scope** in spring but it generate another problem that is when a value select by first drop down let say country and i send value to next drop down of province (to populate province according to country drop down selection) , spring consider it a new request and refresh the bean, So country's drop down value get removed and i get `NullPointerException` while populating provinces.
What should I do now I really get stucked.Please help

Comment: Did the currently accepted answer of aamir *really* solve your concrete problem? Or did you merely accept it due to herd behaviour and/or high votes? I don't do Spring, but the answer of aamir doesn't seem to apply to Spring managed beans at all. Your concrete problem has to be solved by using a different scope, some kind of conversational scope like as "view scope" in JSF and "conversation scope" in CDI. You can find on [Google](http://google.com/search?q=jsf+view+scope+in+spring) examples how to simlulate the JSF view scope in Spring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new bean yourself and put it in the desired scope using `FacesContext`.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("myBean", new MyBean());
```

By using this in your code you can override the current instance of your bean and get rid of old bean.

Comment: So which scope should I use now?

Comment: getSessionMap() tells that your bean would be Session Scope as you are getting it from Session Map

Comment: if using spring this seems the wrong way, as it does not add the bean to the spring context. There are the http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/jsf/FacesContextUtils.html to retrieve a spring context and interact with it.

Comment: Even if it was a normal JSF bean instead of a Spring bean, please note that this naive approach doesn't take `@ManagedProperty`, `@PostConstruct`, etc into account.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the session scope is fine here. I think you need to do a proper management of the selected values of the dropdowns. Once you change DropDown1 you need to reset DropDown2 and DropDown3. Once you change DropDown2 reset DropDown3. By reset I mean to load or filter only the valid data into the model of those components.

Your are using JSF2. Are you working with the `f:ajax` tag? do you have a code snippet available? There may be an issue there, that is a bit tricky here and there.

Comment: yes i think i should use session scope here but my beans are managed by spring.So which scope should I use at spring side?

Comment: session scope as well. make sure the spring config in web.xml is correct so the spring application context is ok. your beans should only be in the spring context, not in faces-config. dont duplicate the config, only use the spring bean resolver (just in case)

Comment: yes i only resgister my bean in applicationcontext.xml .. ok let me try it by using session scope.. Do you think that It will remove values after form submission of an ajax call of JSF?

Comment: no in this case you need to do it manually within the called event. The bean is not recreated automatically in this case when needed. What you could do is put all 3 lists for the drop downs in a model and when the drop down event is coming in just empty the other lists. Unless you find a ready to use component which does that for you I think it is the easiest way to implement this.

Comment: Can you elaborate it in your answer

Comment: There are examples on the web that do mostly the same: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/lamineba/archive/2011/05/12/implementing-cascading-dropdown-jsf-2-0

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [View Scope](http://andyschwartz.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/whats-new-in-jsf-2/#scopes-view) which would be optimal for your use case. But since Spring 3.0 doesn't support the view scope, you'll need to create your custom view scope implementation for Spring to identify. You may refer to [this link](http://www.harezmi.com.tr/spring-view-scope-for-jsf-2-users/) for reference.

Comment: Are you sure that view scope can help in me such case? Because in my case my app is not navigating and it is a ajax based call ..

Comment: If your app does not navigate then what exactly happens after you submit the form ?

Comment: it is an ajax call ... and I tried that links .. They didn't work for me ... even they didn't help me to run view scope when i implemented them :(